# Convert international datestring to ISO-format

Tags: python, datetime, i18n

The function below takes a datestring in the form d-mmm-yyyy and converts it to ISO date format (yyyy-mm-dd). Delimiters may be hyphen, space or `/`,  and Dutch or English month abbreviations may be used.

Now, I know there is `dateutil`, but it returns `unknown string format` if you try to parse something with a non-English month in it. I haven't digested all its documentation, but I think `dateutil` is mainly intended for date calculation. I'm not doing that, I'm just cleaning up user input.

So I wrote my own.

```
import re
.
.

def ISOdate(date): 
    '''
        converts the following date string format to ISO (yyyy-mm-dd):  
        28-okt-1924 (dutch month abbreviations)
        28 oct 1924 (english..) 
         9/nov/2012 (single digit)
    '''

    shortmonths = [
        'jan', 'feb', 'mrt', 'apr', 'mei', 'jun', 
        'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', 
        'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 
        'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'
        ] 

    # Month abbrevs are only different march, may and october.             

    pat = r'(\d{1,2})\s?[-\/]?\s?(\w{3})\s?[-\/]?\s?(\d{4})'

    q = re.match(pat, date)
    if q: 
        year = q.group(3)
        day = int(q.group(1)) 
        month = shortmonths.index(q.group(2).lower()) % 12 + 1
        return u'{}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(year, month, day)
    else:
        # just return input, date fields may be empty
        return date
```

The regex match parses date month and year may not be pretty, but it works and it's easy to expand for other patterns. Likewise for the month number lookup with `index`, which is more concise than a chain of `if, elif` to match month strings to numbers.

Instead of the code between `if q:` and `else:`, I also had this, which uses datetime:

```
year = int(q.group(3))
day = int(q.group(1))
month = shortmonths.index(q.group(2).lower()) % 12 + 1
d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
return u'{:%YY-%m-%d}'.format(d)
```

This works too, but I think the first version is more to-the-point.

I'm always striving for optimal Pythonicness, but I'm by no means a seasoned coder.

Please comment.

Answer (score 2):

Neat stuff.

Suggestions:

Changing `shortmonths` to a dictionary.  This will allow for a pair between numerical months and alphabetical months.  No need to repeat 'jan' for example, as you have it now.

Pythonic: unpack `month, year, day` in a one liner.

Use `datetime`'s `strftime` to format dates...makes life easier in case you want to change the format down the road.

```
import re
import datetime

def ISOdate(date):

    month_d = {'01': 'jan',
               '02': 'feb',
               '03': ['mar', 'mrt'],
               '04': 'apr',
               '05': ['may', 'mei'],
               '06': 'jun',
               '07': 'jul',
               '08': 'aug',
               '09': 'sep',
               '10': ['oct', 'okt'],
               '11': 'nov',
               '12': 'dec'
               }

     pat = r'(\d{1,2})\s?[-\/]?\s?(\w{3})\s?[-\/]?\s?(\d{4})'
     q = re.match(pat, date)

     if q:
         day, month, year = [q.group(idx+1) for idx in range(3)]
         if month.isalpha(): # change from letters to numbers
             month = [k for k, v in month_d.items() if month in v][0]
         out_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
         return datetime.datetime.strftime(out_date, '%Y-%m-%d')  

     else:
         return date
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments/suggestions:

- Use longer variable names to improve readability. For example: `pat` -> `pattern`, `q` -> `match`, `idx` -> `index`.
- Try to follow [pep257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for docstrings
- Why return the same input if it wasn't possible to parse a date? What about returning `None` or maybe raising a `ValueError` exception?
- Regular expressions will always be hard to read, but group names can be used to avoid hardcoding group numbers later:

  ```
  pattern = r'(?P<day>\d{1,2})\s?[-\/]?\s?(?P<month>\w{3})\s?[-\/]?\s?(?P<year>\d{4})'

  match = re.match(pat, date)
  if match:
      year = int(match.group('year'))
      month = match.group('month')
      day = int(match.group('day'))
  ```

Finally, if `dateutil.parser.parse` is already doing a good job for the strings you want to parse except for the month strings, what about replacing the dutch abbreviations with english ones an pass the string to `dateutil.parser.parse`?

```
import dateutil.parser

def ISO_date(date):
    """Convert date string format to ISO (yyyy-mm-dd).

    Examples:
        28-okt-1924 (dutch month abbreviations)
        28 oct 1924 (english..)
         9/nov/2012 (single digit)
    """
    months = {
        'mrt': 'mar',
        'mei': 'may',
        'okt': 'oct',
    }

    for month_dutch, month_english in months.items():
        date = date.replace(month_dutch, month_english)

    return dateutil.parser.parse(date)

print ISO_date('28-okt-1924')
```